# Returning a modified array into string of sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to edit (for demonstration purpose) list of words passed by anything. After which I want to back as I passed it back, but I am stuck on how to get it back as a sentence from an array after the edit. Following is my code

```
function funk(words){
  let arr = words.split(" ")
  arr.forEach((e) =>{
        console.log(`${e}...`);
        //returns in 2 lines but I want it same as I passed i.e. A sentence or string
  })
}

funk("hello world")
```

Comment: simply arr.joint(' ')....

Comment: Here is the [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function

Comment: So is the output you expect a string that reads "hello... world..."?

Comment: @benvc here is an example https://jsbin.com/duqafot/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @benvc I want it on the same line as a sentence or like how it is passed in the argument but with changes appened. right now, if u check in the console, it shows on 2 line

Comment: You use  ` process.stdout.write(`${e}...`);` check my example. its been there

Answer (score 0):

After make the changes you can use `return arr.join(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your array in a different way, for example using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. You can use the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function to join your array back. Taking your same code as an example:

```js
function funk(words){
  let arr = words.split(" ")
  arr = arr.map((e) =>{
    return e + "!"; // You can add any modification to the words of the array here
  })
  // This takes the already modified array and put it together separating its
  // elements by a space
  return arr.join(" ");
}

console.log(funk("hello world")) // Shows "hello! world!"
```

Comment: I don't see how this makes it a bad or incorrect answer for the question that was asked here @Raymond

Comment: 25 minutes ago I posted mine. Everyone of us is using the same map function and same techniques. He obviously doesn't know what he wants, so let's wait until he edits than post new answers

Comment: And thanks @benvc, I didn't even checked the other answers haha but it's okay, I just want to help the community

Answer (score -1):

Your question says returning the array to a combined string, but your comment says making an output on the same line. We are all confused on what you want.

```
// After converting it, let's return it to a combined form
Array.prototype.back = function() {
    return this.join(' ').split('...').join('')
};
// Let's convert it to your format of ['Hello...', 'world...']
String.prototype.convert = function() {
    return this.split(' ').map(w => `${w}...`)
};

let b = 'Hello world'.convert();
let f = b.back();


console.log('Begin', b);
console.log('Final', f);
```

> Output

```
Begin [ 'Hello...', 'world...' ]
Final Hello world
```

And for same line, using your function. You were using `forEach` in a loop, so it will log the console out for each element in the loop. Thats why it was not on the same line. Node.JS example you can just use `process.stdout`

```
function funk(words){
    let arr = words.split(" ")
    arr.forEach((e) =>{
        process.stdout.write(`${e}...`);
        // Will be one line
    })
    // Add this for trailing line console.log('\n');
}
```

> Output (Same Line)

```
hello...world...
```